# Sympy Solve returning type error?

Tags: python-2.7, sympy, solver

I have written a program to solve a transcendental equation using [Sympy Solvers](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html), but I keep getting a TypeError. The code I have written is the following:

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np

x = Symbol('x',positive=True)

def converts(d):
    M = 1.0
    res = solve(-2*M*sp.sqrt(1+2*M/x)-d,x)[0]
    return res
print converts(0.2)
```

which returns the following error:

```
raise TypeError('invalid input: %s' % p)
TypeError: invalid input: -2.0*sqrt(1 + 2/x)
```

I've solved transcendental equations this way before, but this is the first time I'm facing this error.

From what I gather, it looks like Sympy is seeing my input as a string instead of a rational number, but I'm not sure if or why it is so. Can someone please tell me why I'm getting this error and/or how to fix it?

Edit: I've rewritten my code to make it clearer but the result is still the same

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBtiF.png) is the equation I'm trying to solve

Answer (score 0):

Let's first recreate the actual equation.

```
from sympy import *
init_printing()
M, x, d = symbols("M, x, d")
eq = Eq(-2*M * sqrt(1 + 2*M/x) - d, 0)
eq
```

[image: equation before substitutions]

As in your code, we can substitute values: `M=1`, `d=0.2`

```
to_solve = eq.subs({M:1, d:0.2})
to_solve
```

[image: equation after M, d substitutions]

Now, we may attempt to solve it directly

```
solve(to_solve, x)
```

Unfortunately, `solve` fails to find the solution in this case. If we take a closer look at the equation, the square root part should return a negative number for this equation to be valid.

```
-2 * (-1/10) - 0.2 = 0
```

As square root of a number can not be negative, correct me if I'm wrong, sympy is unable to find a value for x such that sqrt(1+2/x) == -1/10

This problem is due to our choice of values for `d` and `M`. Solution exists if M and d are of opposite signs.

```
to_solve = eq.subs({M:-1, d:0.2})
to_solve
```

[image: equation after different substitutions]

```
solve(to_solve, x)
```

> [2.02020202020202]

---

Run this code on [sympy live](http://live.sympy.org/?evaluate=M%2C%20x%2C%20d%20%3D%20symbols(%22M%2C%20x%2C%20d%22)%0Aeq%20%3D%20Eq(-2*M%20*%20sqrt(1%20%2B%202*M%2Fx)%20-%20d%2C%200)%0Aeq%0A%23--%0Ato_solve%20%3D%20eq.subs(%7BM%3A1%2C%20d%3A0.2%7D)%0Ato_solve%0A%23--%0Asolve(to_solve%2C%20x)%0A%23--%0Ato_solve%20%3D%20eq.subs(%7BM%3A-1%2C%20d%3A0.2%7D)%0Ato_solve%0A%23--%0Asolve(to_solve%2C%20x)%0A%23--%0A) and experiment with other values.

Comment: I've fixed the brackets issue and cleared up my code, but I still get the same result.

Comment: I've fixed the brackets issue and cleared up my code, but I still get the same result. "Solve doesn't solve this and returns an empty list". Are you referring to this specific line of code or `solve` in general? If it's the former, what am I doing wrong here? As I said, I've used `solve` several times before to solve a transcendental equation, but this is the first time I am facing this kind of error, so I'm really clueless on how to proceed. Any help in understanding this error would be appreciated

Comment: I meant solve wasn't able to solve this particular equation. (Edited the answer to avoid ambiguity). I'm not familiar with transcendental equations. Anyway, could you post the latex version of equation for clarity?

Comment: I've added an image of the equation. I know it can be solved analytically, but I want to solve this numerically, and then add more terms to the left hand side.

Comment: A transcendental equation is just an equation that is not a polynomial equation, and cannot be solved as such. I was initially trying to solve such an equation, but as I was getting this `TypeError`, I began chopping off terms to see if it was coming from any specific term(s). This was the last term left in the equation- and a very simple one- but even this was returning the same error so I'm quite stumped.